# Install OpenCV error libtiff5-dev : Depends: liblzma-dev but it is not going to be installed

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, apt

I am trying to install openCV on Ubuntu 16.04, I follow this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jXtuAY-FKY
,when compile the source code I got this error

```
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I assume because libtiff5-dev doesn't installed on my machine.I've tried to install it but got error like this :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libtiff5-dev : Depends: liblzma-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

said that "Depends: liblzma-dev"

then I tried to :

> $ sudo apt install liblzma-dev

but got error again :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblzma-dev : Depends: liblzma5 (= 5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2) but 5.2.2-1.3~16.04.york0 is to be installed
```

I got stuck for 4 days, Anyone have solution for this problem ?

Comment: Seems duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275828/error-when-installing-libtiff5-dev

Comment: yes, but that discussion also not yet answered...